Top-level vs. Per-directory 'dirs.proj'?
I'm currently configuring dirs.proj for our very large repo (~1,500 active projects, ~800 C# projects), and wanted to try auto-including every project in the repo using a single top-level dirs.proj file instead of having each directory maintain its own dirs.proj file.
I based my project off of this snippet from this MSBuildSdks README:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.Traversal">
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Build all projects recursively under the "src" folder -->
    <ProjectReference Include="src\**\*.*proj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I also added many path exclusions to rule out searching in build output/package paths, and have a long list of single project excludes as well, but otherwise glob the entire repo.
However, I was recently advised that this is not conventional/recommended, and that it's preferred to use per-directory dirs.proj for the purpose of performance. I tested per-directory and top-level, and found that while per-directory was faster, it was only a difference of ~6 seconds vs. ~8 seconds, which is a drop in the bucket considering a full build of our repo is magnitudes slower than this. Otherwise comparing the two, I see more benefit to top-level in that there's less maintenance required, and a big list of projects not being build is more useful compare to many tiny lists of projects which are being built.
My question is, is there a reason besides performance to prefer per-directory dirs.proj files over per-directory ones?

There are essentially two dirs.proj patterns. The older pattern is described in an article by Sayed Ibrahim. Also see this answer to "How is dirs.proj used?". The Microsoft.Build.Traversal SDK is comparatively very new and could be argued to be a different mechanism but naming the file dirs.proj has been retained.
